# std::variant and incomplete type: how does it work?

Tags: c++, variant

I do understand that `std::variant` works with incomplete type. However, I don't understand how it can works because, in my understanding, `std::variant` must need the maximum size of the types it holds.

So, why does this code does not compile with `s1` and `s2`. How can make it works like `std::variant`?

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct Rect;
struct Circle;

using Shape = std::variant<Rect, Circle>;

template<typename C>
struct S {static constexpr auto s = sizeof(C);};

constexpr auto s1 = S<Rect>::s;
constexpr auto s2 = sizeof(Rect);

struct Circle{};
struct Rect{
    std::vector<Shape> shapes;
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: AFAIK it is undefined behavior to use an incomplete type in a `std::variant`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do understand that std::variant works with incomplete type.

I don't think you do. It doesn't.

> However, I don't understand how it can works because

That makes sense. It can't work, because:

> in my unstanding, std::variant must need the maximum size of the types it holds.

---

This is what the standard says:

> [res.on.functions]
>
> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program.
>   If these components do not meet their requirements, **this document places no requirements on the implementation**.
>
> In particular, the **effects are undefined** in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> - if an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.

There is no specific rule in the section [variant] allowing incomplete types.

Comment: Okay it compiled and works fine, but it is an UB. Thanks :).

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this answer, however nothing in the code is actually trying to instantiate `std::variant<Rect, Circle>`, so it doesn't matter that it doesn't work with incomplete arguments. OP's code fails only because `s1` and `s2` try to take the size of an incomplete type.