# Self-/circular reference in "using" statements

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I've tried defining a variant type for dynamic variables in my program, but I can't seem to be able to make it store a function that returns it as a type.

```
using Value = std::variant<Integer, Float, Function>;
using Function = std::function<Value()>;
```

This won't compile because `Function` needs to be defined at the time `Value` is, but `Function` depends on `Value` too. I've tried fixing this by inlining the `Function` type into the variant template list but it seems that `using` statements can't reference themselves or be forward declared.

My best solution so far has been defining `Function` as a struct so I can forward declare it. This works, but seems so hacky, so I'm wondering if there's  a better way?

```
struct Function;
// define Value
struct Function : std::function<Value()> {};
```

To clarify, `std::function` was used as part of the example because I thought it would be easier to show what I was trying to do and it also was needed for my hacky solution. I'd prefer a way to have this working with plain function pointers too, if possible.

Comment: A simple function pointer works too, I was just using `std::function` because I thought it would make the example simpler, and also worked for my hacky solution

Comment: I'll be honest, I thought using a function pointer would make this easier. But as you mention a `using` can't refer itself. So it doesn't really help.

Comment: Beware that using `std::variant` with incomplete types is Undefined Behavior. See [std::variant and incomplete type: how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226629/stdvariant-and-incomplete-type-how-does-it-work). So it looks like your solution is Undefined Behavior and may not actually work even if it looks like it works when you try it.

Comment: Can you change the function signature to take a pointer to Value?

Comment: The original plan was for the function to return a `std::optional<Value>`, but I omitted it here for the sake of simplicity, but I wouldn't be able to use a pointer return type. Moreover I can't reference the `Value` declaration within or before it.

Comment: note that not only in c++ this is a circular definition, I'd go one step back and reconsider if this is really something you need....

Answer (score 4):

This can't work, because what you are essentially trying to create is this:

`std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<std::variant<Integer, Float, std::function<...()>>()>>()>>()>>()>>()>>()>>()>>()>>()>>()>>;`

So basically you have an infinite recursion within the type declarations.

You need to work around this by using some type that doesn't have a recursive definition, but using a forwarded `struct` directly like you suggest is not an option, because `std::variant` only allows complete types.

What you could do is forward declare your `struct`, and then use a container/wrapper/smart pointer of your choice (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Function>`) in your `std::variant`:

```
struct Function;
using Value = std::variant<Integer, Float, std::unique_ptr<Function>>;
struct Function : std::function<Value()> {};
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is, since it only holds a pointer internally. std::make_unique needs to have the complete type defined first, but std::unique_ptr itself doesn't.

Comment: It looks pretty similar to what one would use for `pimpl` so it should work fine, but wouldn't OP:s original version with `struct Function;` also work the same way?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, it wouldn't. `std::variant` needs its template arguments to be complete types. `Function` is not a complete type in that case. `std::unique_ptr<Function>` is.