# Boost::variant with a object which references the same variant

Tags: c++, boost-variant

How can I have a variant of different objects `A, B, C` where `C` has a reference to the variant?

```
class A {
   ...
};

class B {
   ...
};

class C {
   ...
   std::vector<PossibleValues> storage; // reference to variant
   ...
};

boost::variant<A, B, C> PossibleValues;
```

Comment: Not possible, unless you use pointers. It's the same reason a class or structure can't contain its own type.

Comment: You can forward-declare each class that's `typedef`ed into the variant. Once the `typedef` is declared, define all the classes, then use the `typedef` to define instances of the variant.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Finding it difficult to follow what you mean, could you provide a answer?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:  `std::vector` "is" pointer like. `struct S { std::vector<S> children; };` is possible.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why did you delete your solution? I just tested it and it works.

Comment: `std::variant` cannot have incomplete type, (what my solution does, even if it compiles). It is ill-formed.

Comment: In the answer referenced by @Jarod42, the conclusion looks wrong to me. The key quoted part is "... when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept". A `typedef` declaration is not instantiating. A forward declaration, in this context, is 100% kosher.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: According to [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226629/stdvariant-and-incomplete-type-how-does-it-work) `using V = std::variant<incompleteType>` is ill formed. With boost, it might be fine though. and ignoring typedef, in `C`, we have `std::vector<std::variant<C>>` where `C` is still incomplete.

Comment: Yes, according to the question it's ill-formed. However: I stated the reasoning why I believe the question is incorrect. `typedef` is not instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With correct order, you might have:

```
class A {
   //...
};

class B {
   //...
};

class C;
using PossibleValues = std::variant<A, B, C>;

class C {
   //...
   std::vector<PossibleValues> storage; // reference to variant
   //...
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d3d7078eb3bbd1b)

Comment: It seems that `std::variant` can not have incomplete type, am I right?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier: Indeed from [stdvariant-and-incomplete-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226629/stdvariant-and-incomplete-type-how-does-it-work). :-(