# Resolve self-referencing of nested initializer list datastructures

Tags: c++, c++17, nested-lists, initializer-list, self-reference

I'm trying to solve this puzzle: I'm using a variant `val` which may contain primitive types as well as user-defined containers which could again contain the variant. This kind of self-referential data structures wouldn't be possible if not for the box wrapper object. This wrapper object wraps the containers `array` and `obj` and provides a determinable memory layout because it's just holding on to a pointer to these containers and not the containers itself.

But now here's the problem: To make the brace enclosed initializer list-syntax work with `container`, the box datastructure needs to supply the given std::initializer_list-constructors for series of `keyval` and `val`. However to define val I need to know the complete types of all template arguments involved, including the box object. But this again needs to know val. This creates a reciprocical definition set. How can I resolve that?

Code ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFcSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BflyB1bUC9Y0ExZExcYm2DU0tue0jvf2l5YkAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2BbgoExGHAh9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHAG6NeIYEl9d3ZlsMOy8%2B0ObgIAE9kpgAPqnJiEBTfW4/E7ELwOPaNYhMMGHKy3FFogh7VDRbS45GnQl7ADWmDBb1o5KRtwImBYyQMrOeoIhjFYTwAKoibgT0dFUKofiYAOx4m57BV7cWqCAndAgEBhDJiPAALziUNoeBOINp9LElz2WoI8wOsqlt0VdoAIj8ncrVQR1ZqGNqjfriIbjV9Xhb/Ngrb6bXa5W7FTLXY7FQKAFR7ZKnKFMu7S13%2BWO3LzpIx7BnPZ17NUat5nT4gqsgFgCNINVmkJUSkGY7GXdvKkEksnh9thAh91Ceb75h0iynowdS%2B1JhWDiC2mVyp0JuMr0me73Wj7%2Bg1Gk1HM0My3W9dL%2BXx3OLvMF2eo9HdnFI29O99rmM7l3/j%2BDaHjqAZBmebiXuGkaEDem73omOZPjOopEheFqfvBCrobQv4bv%2B27LjSdIMvuGoouclanO2ZZMLaIDEWCWayiiCY0WIzEWEwCZ/kRhF3ERDYUSWZpZtORFlgyULllR3pNgwLZMKy%2BEPuJSHZihc5EmgghwuExB7AxyReNERrIBixBYmC7bGaZeDmQumH/kWlHvhq77Zk6LkloOGoLmp24Bbco57CwelrouWF7DpDRhHElaoGwUIxXp8WHBWG5/mYZg0MQJrZe2lJPGxMYHNlSg6eg5hmO2XAuu2mXVQQCB4MQVUFX%2B9rZTlrX5TVexmCV%2BHdRVAjtf1RXbrmLoAQFuYcIstCcAArLwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYCUrGsZX%2BDwpAEJoC2LNSIDLRo%2BicJIa0XVtnC8AoIB3edG0LaQcCwDAiAoIlyR0HE5CUGg7Kg/EwBcGYXB8HQrJ5ZQ0TPdEYSNGCnCnZDbCCAA8gwtDY99pBYGFRjiGT%2BDEDUjgvJg71k5gqg1F4rLPaOmBLWTRrRFixBgh4WDPaceAsDjP1UAYwAKAAangmAAO4E5C62nfwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6hk7oCMGEYKB7ZY%2Bh4NE72QIsqAZpkzMALRu2q6WmJY1hcNKexuwTZhvTz9OZC4DDuJ4rR6CEcWzEMCOpOkjgCOMbT5KnmQzIMFS2GHXQMD0YwxxMBf2GnxejH0Cd53oJy9BnDc17nZRJ4sCjLKsetnXT6w8ItK1PWT20cKoCQAGxu5Pkh7MAyDmXDAB0dUQLtvs23suCECQx0I3sHhQ/QBmbFw8y8F9WjzFdN13bzj2kJLkj%2BMv/jLdK/iT%2B/khmJ/ACckhlqkHWptMeb0PpnQuosP6gNlgEGMmOCgEBIYgxPhEfknAJ7T1ntFC2wA9gQEpAwakF8gj4CIGcdUCMtbCFEOIfWtCjZqGembUgyssTJClkPDgq0QHPTHgTDmiDiRUD2Ngmec8F5LzMKvQhR80FpT%2BOfS%2B0DFgIEwEwLA8Q1z3Q4I/SWy1J7L1nmYb%2Bs8P5mI0MtYBoDeDgNsJAq%2Bl1SDXVuno/wI8wGvSgd9G%2BeiQ78NHj45x/jGZ5QjpIIAA)):

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

struct array;
struct obj;
struct keyval;

template <typename T>
struct box
{
    box(std::initializer_list<keyval> init) {

    }
    box(std::initializer_list<val> init) {

    }
    T* ptr_;
};

using val = std::variant<std::monostate, box<array>, box<obj>, int, bool>;

struct obj
{
    obj() {
    }
    obj(std::initializer_list<keyval> init) {
    }
};

struct array
{
    array() {
    }
    array(std::initializer_list<val> init) {
    }
};

struct keyval
{
    keyval() {
    }
    keyval(std::string str, val a) : key_{str}, val_{a} {
    }

    std::string key_;
    val val_ = std::monostate{};
};


struct container : public array, public obj
{
    using array::array;
    using obj::obj;
};

int main()
{
    container some_container = { {"first", true }, { "second", 1 }, { "third", {{"2first", 2}, {"2second", true}} } };
}
```

**Error**:

```
<source>:15:31: error: 'val' was not declared in this scope
   15 |     box(std::initializer_list<val> init) {
      |                               ^~~
<source>:15:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   15 |     box(std::initializer_list<val> init) {
      |                                  ^
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:59:117: error: could not convert '{{"first", true}, {"second", 1}, {"third", {{"2first", 2}, {"2second", true}}}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'container'
   59 |     container some_container = { {"first", true }, { "second", 1 }, { "third", {{"2first", 2}, {"2second", true}} } };
      |                                                                                                                     ^
      |                                                                                                                     |
      |
```

Comment: You simply have to move `using val = std::variant<std::monostate, box<array>, box<obj>, int, bool>;` before the definition of `box
` and forward-declare `box` before it. The using-declaration doesn't cause any instantiation, so that should be fine.

Comment: And technically you will need to reorder some of the stuff after that as well, because `std::initializer_list` is not specified to support incomplete types (although that is likely a standard defect). Define all of the non-template classes first without inline member definitions. Then define all of the members later (as `inline`).

Comment: @user17732522 Can I do that also for constructors (provide inline definitions later)? I guess that would solve my issue. Could you provide an example? Also, I can't move the incomplete type definition before the definition of box because the variant would have undefined behavior.

Comment: `inline obj::obj(std::initializer_list<keyval> init) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @user17732522 But then I get `error: no declaration matches 'obj::obj(std::initializer_list<keyval>)'`

Comment: You need to keep the declaration `obj(std::initializer_list<keyval> init);` (optionally with `inline`) inside the class.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh I thought I could inject it later. Then it doesn't solve my problem (I wanted to use it for the box type and declare + define it after the class which would help)

Comment: The point is that function parameters do not need to have complete types _in a declaration_. They only need to be complete in the _definition_. So by moving the definition out of the class you can delay the requirement for the type to be complete until later. For templates this doesn't matter by the way because their member function definitions are only instantiated when they are (odr-)used the first time anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246398/discussion-between-glades-and-user17732522).

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to declare put the `using` directive before the definition of `struct box`. Since `box` is being referred to in the declaration of `val`, you have to put a forward declaration of `box`.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct box;

using val = std::variant<std::monostate, box<array>, box<obj>, int, bool>;

template <typename T>
struct box {};
```

2. [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) can't be directly initialized from a `std::initializer_list`), which means

```cpp
box<array> b{{"2first", 2},{"2second", true}}; // OK
val v1{b}; // OK
val v2{{"2first", 2},{"2second", true}}; // ERROR
```

That's why the construction of `container` failed.

One simple solution is to provide the type explicitly.

```cpp
container some_container = { {"first", true }, { "second", 1 }, { "third", box<array>{{"2first", 2}, {"2second", true}} } }; // note the box<array>
```

3. Thanks @user17732522 for the comments about incomplete types things.
   The return type or argument types in a function definition are required to be complete, but not in declaration. So you need to put the in-class definition outside after all class involved are complete.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rW75WoYs8)

Comment: Thank you but then at the time of definition of std::variant the type box is incomplete. I thought that would cause UB?

Comment: @glades Umm. Yes it does. Thanks for notification. I'm afraid I have little thoughts about avoiding UB in your case..

Comment: It works on gcc and clang I have tested. I don't understand how though. The thing is it would be possible if I could declare the type size without having to specify constructors as well, as for the definition of the variant only the size would have to be known.

Comment: @glades `using = std::variant</*...*/>;` does not cause instantiation of the `std::variant` specialization, so it doesn't matter that the template arguments are incomplete. Instantiation happens only later when you use it in a context requiring it to be complete.

Comment: @user17732522 I believe you're right. I was a bit confused by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226629/stdvariant-and-incomplete-type-how-does-it-work

Comment: @Nimrod There must have been some misunderstanding in that question. It fails there only because `s1` and `s2` try to take the size of the incomplete type. The rest is correct, because `std::vector` does not require the value type to be complete since C++17. However the given answer is technically correct in everything it is saying. There just seems to be a misunderstanding of what "_works with_" means.