# how to split cyclic dependency with 'using' directive

Tags: c++, header, typedef, using, circular-dependency

Suppose classes A and B. Each can construct the other:

```cpp
// A.hpp
#pragma once
class B;
class A {
  B foo();
};
```

```cpp
// A.cpp
#include <A.hpp>
#include <B.hpp>
B foo(){ return B(); }
```

```cpp
// B.hpp
#pragma once
class A;
class B {
  A foo();
};
```

```cpp
// B.cpp
#include <B.hpp>
#include <A.hpp>
A foo(){ return A(); }
```

Let's introduce a new type:

```cpp
// A_or_B.hpp
#pragma once

#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
// or
class A;
class B;

using A_or_B = std::variant<A, B>;
```

Let's return A_or_B from A and B:

```cpp
// A.hpp
#pragma once

#include "A_or_B.hpp" // woops!  the type for A_or_B is not resolved:
class A {
  A_or_B foo();
};
```

Justifications for the whoops:

1. if we use an include in A_or_B.hpp then A_or_B will not be able to include A (since the header guard) - so it will be referencing a non-existant type.
2. if we use a forward declaration then A_or_B will use uncomplete types and will not be usable in the linking stage

The cyclic problem doesn't occur between `A` and `B` because we split the declaration and implementation between `hpp` and `cpp` files. contrary to classes - `typedefs` or `using` directives can't be split.

what can be done to solve this?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are to solve? Why should both `A` and `B` have a method that returns either `A` or `B`?

Comment: it's a state machine. the object that is of type ```A_or_B``` is the current state. The classes themselves are the states.

Comment: Make `A_or_B` an actual class.

Comment: Using `std::variant<A, B>;` with forward-declared classes is UB. The cyclic dependency here can not be solved because every step requires complete type. It can easily be solved by introducing pointer somewhere, for example `using A_or_B = std::variant<A *, B *>;` Or maybe even a hierarchy of classes `using A_or_B = ::std::unique_pt<Base>;`

Comment: So why don't you go the typical way using inheritance? `class State {virtual State* foo() = 0;}; class A: public State{/*override foo*/}; class B: public State{/*override foo*/}};`? You can't do what you want, as noted above.

Comment: I'll make it an actual class -  that way I get to implement an ```advance``` function for the state machine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `A_or_B` as a typedef for `std::variant<A, B>` without defining `A` and `B`. Only to instantiate an object of type `A_or_B` do you need the definitions.

```
// A.hpp
#include "A_or_B_fwd.hpp"

class A {
    A_or_B foo();
};

// B.hpp
#include "A_or_B_fwd.hpp"

class B {
    A_or_B foo();
};

// A_or_B_fwd.hpp
#include <variant>

class A;
class B;

using A_or_B = std::variant<A, B>;

// A_or_B.hpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include "A_or_B_fwd.hpp"

// A.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include "A_or_B.hpp"

A_or_B A::foo() { /* ... */ }

// B.cpp analogously
```

Using "-fwd.hpp"-style headers can be reasonable when forward declarations are more complex than `class X;`
The standard library also does it with `<iosfwd>`.

Comment: and A.cpp will have: 1. include A.hpp 2. include A_or_B.hpp 3. definitions. right?

Comment: "You can define A_or_B as a typedef for std::variant<A, B> without defining A and B" - you can not. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57226751/7860670

Comment: @user7860670 [You can absolutely](https://godbolt.org/z/Wvxjs1r9Y). In the question you linked, `Rect` is indeed incomplete where `Shape` is instantiated. This does not need to be the case here.

Comment: @EyalKamitchi Yes, and then define `A::foo()` and `B::foo` in their respective .cpp files.

Answer (score 2):

You can forward declare `A_or_B` and then eventually define it as a class that publicly inherits from the variant type.

```
// A.hpp
#pragma once
class A_or_B;
class A {
    A_or_B foo();
};

// B.hpp
#pragma once
class A_or_B;
class B {
    A_or_B foo();
};

// A_or_B.hpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

class A_or_B : public std::variant<A, B> {
public:
    using base = std::variant<A, B>;
    using base::base;
    using base::operator=;
};
```