# C++ circular reference of classes members

Tags: c++, class, circular-reference

I have the following code (simplified for brevity). I'm making an interpreter and executor of simple "programs", which basically consist of commands and loops.

```
class Command
{
    int code, arg; // whatever
};

class Loop;
class Statement;

class Scope
{
    std::vector<Statement> statements;
public:
    Statement& appendCmd(const Command& = {}); // works
    Statement& appendLoop(const Loop& = {}); // cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'const Loop &'
    Statement& appendLoop(const Loop& = Loop()); // use of undefined type 'Loop'
};

class Loop
{
    Scope scope;
    int iters;
};

class Statement
{
    std::variant<std::monostate, Command, Loop> sttmnt;
};
```

The problem is, `class Loop` requires definition of class `Scope` for the member variable, while `class Scope` requires definition of class `Loop` to construct the default value of argument.
How can I solve this? Also I'd rather not make any of them nested inside any other.

I already had this problem before, but it could be omitted by moving method definitions out of the header file. However default argument value must be in the header...

Edit: Updated the code which hopefully removes the UB of `variant` having undefined type.

Comment: Instead of the default argument use overloading to resolve the issue. Add a function with no arguments that adds a default item and change the function with a single argument to actually require the parameter. I do wonder if these classes actually have meaningful default states. If not then just abandon the default completely.

Comment: [You can't use incomplete types with `std::variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226629/), so `using Statement = std::variant<std::monostate, Command, Loop>;` is invalid since `Loop` hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ive seen this. To be precise, instead of `using` I have a separate class `Statement` defined at the very end, which has a member of the `variant` type. Idk if that fixes it though. I wonder why it compiles if the order in the wuestion is wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Please see updated code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I guess that is the cleanest solution.
The `Loop` definitely has a valid default state - simply with empty `Scope`, ready to have commands added into it.

Comment: [C++17 allows `std::vector` to specify an incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975491/), but earlier C++ versions did not. But in any case, `appendLoop()` simply can't specify a default value for its `Loop` parameter when `Loop` is an incomplete type, as the compiler doesn't know how to construct a `Loop` yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose one solution would be:

```
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

class Scope;

class Command
{
    int code, arg; // whatever
};

class Loop
{
    std::unique_ptr <Scope> scope;
    int iters;
};

using Statement = std::variant<std::monostate, Command, Loop>;

class Scope
{
    std::vector<Statement> statements;
public:
    Statement& appendCmd(const Command& = {});
    Statement& appendLoop(const Loop& = {});
};
```

But @RetiredNinja's comment is highly relevant.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the rearrangement. Please see the updated code, is the behavior now well-defined? I'd rather avoid pointers to prevent any possibility of circular reference in the memory structure.
Though maybe I should use pointers inside the variant, not to waste memory for the widest type? Especially that this code is intended for embedded application...

Comment: You should not edit the question after people have answered it - it muddies the waters.  Using pointers (I would use `std::unique_ptr`) in the variant is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the best solution in terms of practice, but this is something I have done before.

```
class Command
{
    int code, arg; // whatever
};

class Loop;
class Statement;
extern const Loop emptyLoop;

class Scope
{
    std::vector<Statement> statements;
public:
    Statement& appendCmd(const Command& = {}); // works
    Statement& appendLoop(const Loop& = emptyLoop);
};

class Loop
{
    Scope scope;
    int iters;
};

class Statement
{
    std::variant<std::monostate, Command, Loop> sttmnt;
};

//In Loop.cpp
const Loop emptyLoop{};
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/zrex9WE7T for a partial demo.